# Location of Dash Plotly Flask WSGI error logging on Apache2

Tags: python, flask, apache2, mod-wsgi, plotly-dash

I have a Dash Plotly app running on an EC2 instance. When I run the local Flask server, I can open a port and the code runs on that port number. So I don't receive errors in the console or  on the page. But when I run it on the instance's Apache2 WSGI server at port 80, the webpage reports an internal server error on the default page. However, I can't find any python errors in the Apache2 logging at:

```
sudo tail -100 /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Example output for times the webpage reports an internal server error:

```
[Thu Jun 04 22:08:19.756897 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 13197:tid 139903817145280] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Jun 04 22:08:19.825966 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 13619:tid 140443934772160] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.7.1 Python/3.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jun 04 22:08:19.826097 2020] [core:notice] [pid 13619:tid 140443934772160] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Jun 04 22:15:02.466329 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 13619:tid 140443934772160] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Jun 04 22:15:02.543244 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 13765:tid 140495801015232] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.7.1 Python/3.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jun 04 22:15:02.543333 2020] [core:notice] [pid 13765:tid 140495801015232] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

According to my FlaskApp.wsgi file, the errors are collected at:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/")

from FlaskApp import server as application
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. The `/etc/apache2/sites-available/FlaskApp.conf` file is where the actual logging output directory and file is set:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName http://ec2-x-xxx-xx-xx.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
                ServerAdmin default@email.net
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/FlaskApp-error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/FlaskApp-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

So in the case of a default Apache2 install as root, the output is located at:
`/var/log/apache2/FlaskApp-error.log`

Here I can access python error output:

```
[Fri Jun 05 10:56:11.008176 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 21235:tid 140495518934784] [client 77.160.155.4:47962] mod_wsgi (pid=21235): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp.wsgi'.
[Fri Jun 05 10:56:11.008233 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 21235:tid 140495518934784] [client 77.160.155.4:47962] mod_wsgi (pid=21235): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp.wsgi$
[Fri Jun 05 10:56:11.008315 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 21235:tid 140495518934784] [client 77.160.155.4:47962] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Jun 05 10:56:11.008344 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 21235:tid 140495518934784] [client 77.160.155.4:47962]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
[Fri Jun 05 10:56:11.008349 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 21235:tid 140495518934784] [client 77.160.155.4:47962]     from FlaskApp import server as application
[Fri Jun 05 10:56:11.008355 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 21235:tid 140495518934784] [client 77.160.155.4:47962]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
[Fri Jun 05 10:56:11.008358 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 21235:tid 140495518934784] [client 77.160.155.4:47962]     from utils import Header, make_dash_table, table_link, pandas_shortener
[Fri Jun 05 10:56:11.008372 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 21235:tid 140495518934784] [client 77.160.155.4:47962] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```